# What is the 12c alternative to alter index rebuild online parameters ('sync')

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-text

We have an index defined as followed

```
alter index my_index rebuild online parameters ('sync');
```

During 12c testing, we are getting this error

```
DRG-11000: invalid keyword SYNC
```

It seems [Oracle have deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/release_changes.htm#CCREF99012) the sync option in 12c and are recommending to use `CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX`

Could someone give an example of new syntax applicable to my index?

Comment: Downvotes! What gives, anonymous knights of the down arrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look a the doc, and I would suggest you do:

```
exec ctx_dll.sync_index( 'MY_INDEX' )
```

Comment: thanks. Does this replace entirely the "alter index my_index rebuild" command, or is some version of that without the 'sync' bit still needed?

Comment: It looks to me like this replaces it.